# Doubts about composite of functions are associative and monotonic functions.

Tags: functions

Okay, so lately we've been introduced in our class 12 starting to relation and functions and I've some doubts:

1)The book just said that the composite of a function is associative with no proof. I saw couple of proofs but they all confused me? Is there any intuitive way for realising it?

2)I get what are monotonic and strict monotonic functions but there was this example tha $f(x) =3x-1$ is a strict increasing function and $f(x) 1-3x$ is strict decreasing function because the absolute $f(x) =|x$| is neither increasing nor decreasing. I dont understand what all this has to do with the absolute value of $x$ please explain this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

Let it be that $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to C$ and $h:C\to D$ are functions.

Then $f$ and $g$ together induce a function $A\to C$ which is prescribed by:$$a\mapsto g(f(a))$$

This function is the so-called composition of $f$ and $g$ and the function is denoted as $g\circ f$.

So note that we actually have:$$(g\circ f)(a)=g(f(a))$$

Likewise we have the composition $h\circ g:B\to D$ with:$$(h\circ g)(b)=h(g(b))$$
Again two compositions show up: $h\circ(g\circ f):A\to D$ and $(h\circ g)\circ f:A\to D$.

Associativity of composition means in essence that these functions are exactly the same.

This can be verified by showing that $(h\circ(g\circ f))(a)=((h\circ g)\circ f)(a)$ for any arbitrarily chosen $a\in A$.

Note that: $(h\circ(g\circ f))(a)=h((g\circ f)(a))=h(g(f(a)))\tag1$and$((h\circ g)\circ f)(a)=(h\circ g)(f(a))=h(g(f(a)))\tag2$
where RHS of $(1)$ and $(2)$ is the same.

---

P.S. concerning:

> "I saw couple of proofs but they *all* confused me"

Then there is quite a chance that this is *again* a proof that confuses you. If so then make clear *what confuses you*, so that your confusion might be taken away.

Comment: I got it! thanks

Comment: can you also answer my next question? @drhab

Comment: Sorry but just like you I cannot discern a link between  $|x|$ being not monotone and $3x-1$ being strictly monotone.

Comment: okay no problem